# Data factory azure blob source - wildcard

Tags: csv, azure, azure-blob-storage, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-factory

I was led to believe that you can wildcard the filename property in an Azure Blob Table source object.

I want to pick up only certain csv files from blob storage that exist in the same directory as other files I don't want to process:

i.e.

root/data/GUJH-01.csv

root/data/GUJH-02.csv

root/data/DFGT-01.csv

I want to process GUJH*.csv and not DFGT-01.csv

Is this possible?  If so, why is my blob source validation failing, informing me that the file does not exist (The message reports that the root/data blob does not exist.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question..

There's not a wildcard but there is a 'Starts With' which will work in my scenario:

Instead of root/data/GUJH*.csv I can do root/data/GUJH on the folderPath property and it will bring in all root/data/GUJH files..

:)

Comment: Took me a long time to work this out too. Now I wonder how you would limit it CSV files ony?

Comment: Just make sure `filePath` is not specified and `folderPath` has the full path including the filename. Also make sure you run the correct _timeslice_. I was just running a random timeslice which in turn passed in the wrong parameter which means it couldn't find the file

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some more detail here because I'm finding this a very difficult learning curve and I'd like to document this for my sake and others.

Given a sample file like this (no extensions in this case) in blob storage,

`ZZZZ_20170727_1324`

We can see the middle part is in yyyyMMdd format.

This is uploaded to folder `Landing` inside container `MyContainer`

this was part of my dataset definition::

```
    "typeProperties": {
        "folderPath": "MyContainer/Landing/ZZZZ_{DayCode}",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "columnDelimiter": "\u0001"
        },
        "partitionedBy": [
            {
                "name": "DayCode",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "SliceStart",
                    "format": "yyyyMMdd"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Note that it's a 'prefix', which you will see in the log / error messages, if you can find them (good luck)

If you want to test loading this particular file you need to press the 'Diagram' button, then drill into your pipeline until you find the *target* dataset - the one the file is being loaded *into* (I am loading this into SQL Azure). Click on the target dataset, now go and find the *correct* timeslice. In my case I need to find the timeslice with a *start timeslice of 20170727* and run that one.

This will make sure the correct file is picked up and loaded in to SQL Azure

Forget about manually running pipelines or activities - thats just not how it works. You need to run the output dataset under a timeslice to pull it through.